failure to connect mobsf container to genymotion vm via ADB
I set an genymotion vm on AWS, and I am able to login to port 443, and confirmed that 5555 is working for adb,


then I launched mobsf using docker
docker run --name mobsf -it --rm -p 8000:8000 -p 1338:1338 \
-e MOBSF_ANALYZER_IDENTIFIER="13.212.119.90:5555" \
opensecurity/mobile-security-framework-mobsf:latest

However, when I click to launch dynamic analysis, it failed. I see the following from mobsf container log:
[ERROR] 13/Sep/2024 12:10:18 - VM's /system is not writable. This VM cannot be used for Dynamic Analysis.
[ERROR] 13/Sep/2024 12:10:18 - Cannot Connect to 13.212.24.231:5555
[ERROR] 13/Sep/2024 12:10:18 - Internal Server Error: /android_dynamic/5ee4829065640f9c936ac861d1650ffc

And, the following from genymotion logs:
09-13 08:15:03.645 I/hwc.cf_x86( 445): Sent 3660 syncs in 60s
09-13 08:15:05.449 I/adbd ( 2298): host-13: read thread spawning
09-13 08:15:05.449 I/adbd ( 2298): host-13: already offline
09-13 08:15:05.449 I/adbd ( 2298): host-13: write thread spawning
09-13 08:15:09.549 I/adbd ( 2298): host-12: write thread spawning
09-13 08:15:09.549 I/adbd ( 2298): host-12: read thread spawning
09-13 08:15:09.549 I/adbd ( 2298): host-12: read failed: Success
09-13 08:15:09.549 I/adbd ( 2298): host-12: connection terminated: read failed
09-13 08:15:09.549 I/adbd ( 2298): host-12: already offline
09-13 08:15:09.549 I/adbd ( 2298): destroying transport host-12
09-13 08:15:09.549 I/adbd ( 2298): BlockingConnectionAdapter(host-12): stopping
09-13 08:15:09.549 I/adbd ( 2298): BlockingConnectionAdapter(host-12): stopped
09-13 08:15:09.549 I/adbd ( 2298): BlockingConnectionAdapter(host-12): destructing
09-13 08:15:09.549 I/adbd ( 2298): BlockingConnectionAdapter(host-12): already stopped

If I get into the mobsf container shell, and trying to adb connect, it seems connection is fine, but /system is indeed read only.
mobsf@f7aaf538daaa:~/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF$ adb connect 13.212.24.231:5555
already connected to 13.212.24.231:5555

mobsf@f7aaf538daaa:~/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF$ adb shell
cloud:/ # cd /system

cloud:/system # touch a
touch: 'a': Read-only file system

I am guessing there is some communication issues in between, and I have set the security group for port 5555 of genymotion to 0.0.0.0; is there anything else I am missing here?
thanks!

okay, I just saw the below from https://github.com/MobSF/docs/blob/master/dynamic_analyzer.md
"Only Android images upto API 28 is supported! Newer Android AVDs does not offer a writable /system and hence cannot work with MobSF."
